# How to add information to string

Tags: php, arrays, database, string

In the database I have 10 points with lat and lng by

```
foreach($points as $point){
    ->($point->lng, $point->lat);
}
```

I have the information for all of them and now I need to add the information to

```
Mapper::map(5, -2) HERE;
```

So it should be looking like

```
Mapper::map(5, -2)->marker($point->lng, $point->lat)->marker($point->lng, $point->lat)...;
```

What is the best way to do that.

Comment: What does your `Mapper` class does? This method accepts `array` of only two `integer` as params? You probably just need to rewrite this method. If you need help with that, update the question with more info.

Comment: Does `map` return an object? Do you want to add a property to that object that is an array of objects with (longitude, latitude)? Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: Mapper is creating a google map and you can add a marker for example with ->marker(lng, lat) but I want to add this information from the database automaticly so with the foreach I have created ->marker1(lng,lat)->marker2(lng, lat)-> .... and all I need is just to add this information after the class Mapper ....so at all in the end it should be looking like Mapper::map(5, -2)->($point->lng, $point->lat)->($point->lng, $point->lat)...;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly:

```
$map = Mapper::map(5, -2);

foreach($points as $point){
    $map = $map->marker($point->lng, $point->lat);
}

var_dump($map)
```

But it reallys depends of what this method returns. Not sure if this will work for you without knowing what the code is doing. =/